# How can I make a pictograph?

Tags: windows, charts

How could I make a chart similar to the one below?

[image: the chart]

Of course, I could use an app like Microsoft Paint, but that would be too time-consuming and awkward. What would be a simple way to do this?

Comment: This type of chart is called a pictograph.

Comment: @Rajib or an Infographic is corporate speak.

Answer (score 16):

You can get close in Excel:

Create your graph, as you normally would by selected your data points and inserting a graph.

Once you have your graph, select the actual graph item (In this case the bars themselves)

[image]

- Now right click the bar, and choose *Format Data Point*
- Go to the *Fill* tab
- Check Picture or Texture Fill
- Select your image from the *File...* button
- Set *Stack and Scale* to units per picture to 1 if you want one image per unit in your datachart

[image]

You should now have your Excel Chart with images, similar to what you want.

[image]

There are some short comings, but it gets you close with more or less standard software.

---

**EDIT**

By using a stacked bar and switching the row / column values and then changing the 2 fill pattern to a new Orange stick figure, I was easily able to get closer:

[image]

Thanks to @Rik for the suggestion.

Comment: I'd prefer something more visually appealing.

Comment: realize this took 20 seconds in Excel and paint to make the stick figures. Making it look more refined would not be hard, starting with a more professional base graphic.

Comment: +1 - Love the stick figurines ;) @Miscreant With it you should be able to create something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/R3GG1Ih.png) or [this](http://i.imgur.com/BKKN7m0.jpg). Not sure if you can get a different color per line. You also may want to look into [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2013/10/10/new-release-people-graph-and-wikipedia-apps-for-office.aspx) from Microsoft mentioning a free "People Graph app v1.1 for Excel 2013". I didn't post that as a separate answer because i think this one works good enough (and i don't have Office2013 handy to test it myself)

Comment: @Rik to get different colors per lines, you can edit each bar and use a different image. So for my stick figures, I could use flood fill for the black lines and paint it blue, red etc and save a new image / color for each bar. So doable for sure.

Answer (score 9):

Here is another solution using Excel 2013.
All credits go to Rik who mentioned the [People Graph](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/store/people-graph-WA104104476.aspx?queryid=152e98ab%2Dd171%2D463d%2Da318%2Dd4cda4d94774&css=people%20graph) app in [a comment](https://superuser.com/questions/682724/what-app-can-i-use-to-make-a-chart-like-this#comment865337_682727).

[image]

1. Installation:

   - Navigate to the [People Graph](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/store/people-graph-WA104104476.aspx?queryid=152e98ab%2Dd171%2D463d%2Da318%2Dd4cda4d94774&css=people%20graph) app site with your internet browser
   - Login with your Microsoft account
   - Click "Add"
2. Open Excel 2013 and write these values in the first 4 cells (A1:B2)
   [image]
3. Click "Insert" at the ribbon bar and choose "Apps for Office" 
   [image]
4. Select "People Graph" and click "Insert"
5. - Hover over the app window, click the table icon and press the "Select your data" button
     [image]
   - Select your data
   - You also have the ability to change the diagram's title (I chose "What do they like?" in the first picture)
6. You can play with the pre-defined themes, colors or cliparts by clicking on the wrench icon
   [image]

Comment: Exporting the chart as an image file: right-click it and choose "Save Picture As".

Answer (score 4):

If you can find a nice Unicode character to represent your figures, you can use Excel's `REPT` formula:

`=REPT("☺", 8)`

Just zoom in in Excel (or change font size) *et voila*!

Answer (score 2):

These style of images are generally called infographics. Unless you're looking for something dynamic or programmatically generated, I would forego the Excel suggestions, and focus on something like Photoshop or GIMP.

The caveat being, the skills to use these programs, or at least make the end product to look good, will take time to develop. Which can be it's own kind of reward.